# Why is the app crashing when I try to append an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I am importing an array from parse, and I want to add that array to an array of arrays, but the app crashes when it tries to append the imported array. Why is that occurring and how can I fix it? Crash error is `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0` I commented the append line and it does not crash, so it has to be that line.

```
 var animalarray: [[String]] = []    

 let query = PFQuery(className: "animals")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil{

                    for object in objects!{

                        if let animalss = object["CoordinateTest"]{
                            print("coord \(animalss)")
                            self.animalarray.append(animalss as! [String])//crashes here

                          }
                  }
             }
        }
```

Comment: what appears in the log from the `print("coord \(animalss)")` line?

Comment: `coord ( "dog", "cat")`

Comment: If I had to guess, `animalss` is not actually an array of Strings, and your force casting is causing the crash.

Comment: Well in parse its an array of strings.

Comment: set a breakpoint at the line of the `print` and check what type `animals` is of

Comment: In general you should avoid force casting, I suggest you add `as? [String]` to the `if` line, and in the `else` block check why it's not being cast properly. This might not be the solution to your question but might help you narrow down the issue.

Comment: how would the else statement look @EmilioPelaez, and that is what I originally did, but nothing would be printed.

Comment: @stackerleet if nothing was being printed when you did that, that's a clear indication that your `animalss` wasn't a `[String]`!

Comment: Yeah, but it's an array in the Parse database, what else could it be?

Comment: `else { print(object["CoordinateTest"]) }` Also a good idea to store it to a variable, add a breakpoint and check the type.

Comment: In the second comment he already showed us the the value of `animalss` which is `( "dog", "cat")` (according to him anyway).

Comment: @EmilioPelaez it says it is a NSMutableString

Comment: @stackerleet that is weird. Can you update the answer with a screenshot of your parse column? Also, print the whole object (`print(object)`), it usually prints all the keys and values associated stored in the object.

Comment: I would move the `as! [String]` from the append to the `if` statement - `if let animalss=object["CoordinateTest"] as! [String]` - then at least you won't get a crash, but you will need to set a breakpoint to work out what `object["CoordinateTest"]` *is* if it doesn't enter the `if` clause

Answer (score -2):

You should create a method that retrieves the data, and use queries to specify what you want. Also you should create a temporary variable to hold to retrieved data and append that variable to the array.

Ex.)

```
var animalsArray:   [String] = []

func retrieveData(){
        let query = PFQuery(className: "animals")
        query.whereKey("Key", equalTo: object)
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (object:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

    if ( error != nil ){
        print(error?.localizedDescription, error?.userInfo)
    } else {

        for temp: PFObject in object! {
            let animals:    String       = temp["CoordinateTest"]         as! String

            self.animalsArray.append(animals!)
        }
      }  
    }
}
```